# generating random vectors of constant sum in matlab

Tags: matlab

How to generate a D dimensional random vector whose elements are real numbers between 0 and 1 with their sum equal to a constant value like w which is less than or equal to D. A random vector like R:

```
R = [r1 r2 ... rD]; 
0<=ri<=1;
r1 +r2+ ... +rD = w; 
w<=D;
inputs: w, D;
```

Answer (score 0):

If this what you are looking for? I used pi as the target sum, but you could use whatever:

```
x = rand(1000,1);
x = pi * x / sum(x);
sum(x) - pi

  ans    4.4409e-16
```

Comment: this isnt correct for any D and w, as may generate xi greater than 1

Comment: @Reza_va Sorry. I guess I don't fully understand your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify which distribution your random numbers should follow (and I hope the answer is not "Uniform"), the easiest solution I can figure out involves the [Dirichlet Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution):

```
% Define the parameters...
D = 100;
w = 64;

% Draw a sample of D values from the Dirichlet Distribution...
a = ones(1,D);
R = gamrnd(repmat(a,1,1),1,1,D);
R = R ./ repmat(sum(R,2),1,D);

% Adjust R according to w...
R = R .* w;

% Test the output with tolerance...
R_sum = sum(R);
abs(R_sum - w) < (1e4 * eps(min(R_sum,w)))
```

Comment: Thank you man, however, unfortunately I require uniform distribution. Also, I am going to close this question as I found a similar one in stackoveroverflow. and the answer is given in: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9700-random-vectors-with-fixed-sum